# правильно кодировать домен

Tags: html

есть домен `http://www.schreinerei.sch&auml;ufl.com/datenschutz` правильно ли я понимаю, что верным форматом этого домена будет `http://www.schreinerei.xn--schufl-dua.com/datenschutz` т.е. конвертация html сущности и обработка функцией `idn_to_ascii('http://www.schreinerei.schäufl.com/datenschutz', IDNA_NONTRANSITIONAL_TO_ASCII, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46)`?

Comment: Ну раз полученный адрес успешно открывается, то видимо да

Comment: я хочу сделать как правильно, открывается он и с символами > 127

Comment: Если он вставлен в html, то браузер это сделал за вас и особо заморачиваться не обязательно. Если, например, вы хотите постлать эту ссылку по почте и рассчитываете на древние почтовые клиенты, то стоит преобразовать в `xn--....`

Comment: @Alexey Ten да, я так и делаю, просто хотелось убедиться, что это верный тип записи